# Mapping of Google GeoReverse location fields with Google Place fields (as used by Google Jobs API)

Tags: google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding

Does anyone have a mapping between "Address Component Types" returned by Google's [Geocoding ReverseGeoCoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding) service and [Google Jobs API's](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/job-postings) JobLocation properties?

Many fields have obvious mappings but I can't find a definitive list of the fields that JobLocation uses from [Place](http://schema.org/Place).

I am trying to populate a JobLocation for Google's Job API using data returned by Google's ReverseGeoCoding.

The `administrative_area_level_*` fields are particularly tricky to know how to map.

Comment: Could the "-1" person add a comment? Is it the use of hyperlinks rather than copying those parts into SO? I'm left guessing without the "-1" person leaving a constructive comment. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following mappings acceptable to [Google's test](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool)

Google Maps API field names -> Google Jobs API property name

```
 'address_locality' -> 'addressLocality'
 'administrative_area_level_1' -> 'addressRegion'
 'administrative_area_level_2' -> 'addressLocality'
 'postal_code' -> 'postalCode'
 'country' -> 'addressCountry'
```

and

```
'street_number' + ' ' + 'route' -> 'streetAddress'
```

I am not comfortable with the last mapping as it hardcodes the order of the concatenation but it's probably workable for Google's Job API.